# Convert static file from XCode prjoect to Data

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to read a static file from my XCode project and send it using OutputStream. Regarding writing to the stream, I know how to do it, but I cannot find a way of reading `raw` file from a folder and converting it to Data format, how it could be done?

Comment: What is the "raw" file? Plist? Text file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Data(contentsOf: URL)`